# Having trouble parsing the data recieved from requests.get() using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Here's what i have, it's a very basic set of code

```
import requests
import json


response = requests.get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=cincinnati")
data  = response.json()
```

When i check the type of 'data' it says that it's a list, so i tried

```
for point in data:
    print(point.name)
```

However, that gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I thought it was a list? Not a dictionary. And when i directly do print(data), it does indeed show that each object within the list of data has a name attribute.

I'm sure this is some stupid mistake, but what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is a `list` of `dict`s.
The elements you're iterating over, thusly are `dict`s and you cannot access them by attribute access. You need to acces their keys by their respective names.

```py
for point in data:
    print(point['name'])
```